# Why statically lodaded kernel symbols T.1018, T.932 and T.689 are not matching from the System.map to kallsyms for the same vmlinux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, powerpc

I am facing a problem where statically loaded modules symbols are not matching from the System.map to kallsyms.

I am using power pc based development board which is running 2.6 kernel.

Normally System.map will have static modules symbols and kallsyms will have static as well as dynamically loaded modules symbols.

But in my system when the system boots some symbols name are not matching form the System.map to kallsyms. My system is not having any loadable modules. I have used lsmod to cross verify that (lsmod shows nothing).

Because of these symbols mismatch i am getting crash once i am trying to load a module. To solve the crash once changed the required symbols from the kallsyms to the System.map, able to load the module.

So System.map will have symbols:

c01e3b5c t T.108

c01fb9ac t T.932

c02ea480 t T.689

and kallsyms will have symbols:

c01e3b5c t T.1016

c01fb9ac t T.930

c02ea480 t T.687

The difference in the symbols from the System.map to the kallsyms is only the symbol names. All the mismatched symbols have the same address in the System.map and kallsyms. And as i know kernel will look only for the address, but in  my case why crash is happening even though symbol address
is same?

Why symbol mismatch from the System.map to the kallsyms from the same vmlinux?

Why crash is not happening while changing the symbols name from the kallsyms to the System.map?

What is the dependency involved between System.map to the kallsyms?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the mismatches?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: can you edit your question, to include the example content of `kallsysms` and `System.map`, where the entries differ from what you expect?

Comment: System.map will have symbols T.1018, T.932, and T.689 for an address but kallsyms have different symbols T.1016, T.930 and T.687 for the same address. So because of the mismatch in the symbols i was getting crash. So to resolve the crash i have changed the symbols in the System.map